# Threads blocking while accessing Mojarra JSF Flash in a clustered environment

Tags: java, jsf, jboss, infinispan, mojarra

I'm running a large Java EE 7 application on a two-node JBoss cluster which was recently upgraded from JBoss EAP 6 to JBoss EAP 7.0.4. Intermittently, the application runs into a problem where access becomes very slow, up to the point that the application becomes difficult to access. After a couple of minutes, the issue resolves itself automatically, and operation returns to normal.

Thread dump analysis shows that the incident is caused by the following behavior:

1. A **thread A** tries to write to the session cache, but has to wait to acquire a lock to the cache entry. It is put in **TIMED_WAITING** state.
2. A **thread B** tries to obtain the JSF `Flash` for the same session. In doing so, it tries to update the session, but because **thread A** is already locking the session, it is put in **BLOCKED** state.
3. *All* **threads C** that try to obtain the JSF `Flash` (for *any* session) are put in **BLOCKED** state, thus making the application unresponsive.

Step 1 and 2 are caused by the fact that we're using a synchronous distributed Infinispan session cache, and don't really cause a problem as the locking is local to one user session. Step 3, however, is extremely problematic, because a blocked update to *one user*'s session suddenly impacts *all users*.

The stack traces for all **threads C** are identical:

> stackTrace:
> java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)   at
> com.sun.faces.context.flash.ELFlash.getFlash(ELFlash.java:318)
>
> - waiting to lock <0x00007ef80a75e260> (a **io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletContextImpl**)

Now this was very surprising to me. Why would all requests trying to obtain the JSF flash be blocked by the [`ServletContext`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html)—which is expected to be **global** to the application? The cause can be found in the Mojarra [`ELFlash`](https://github.com/javaserverfaces/mojarra/blob/2.2.12/jsf-ri/src/main/java/com/sun/faces/context/flash/ELFlash.java#L318) source code (line 318 contains the `synchronized` statement):

```
if (appMap.get(EnableDistributable.getQualifiedName()) != null) {
    synchronized (extContext.getContext()) {
        if (extContext.getSession(false) != null) {
            SessionHelper sessionHelper = SessionHelper.getInstance(extContext);
            if (sessionHelper == null) {
                sessionHelper = new SessionHelper();
            }
            sessionHelper.update(extContext, flash);
        }
    }
}
```

In a nutshell, what's happening here that at some point during the development of Mojarra 2.2.x, the developers [decided](https://github.com/ngriffin7a/mojarra-svn2git-2.2.x/commit/5b17d3bb2551654cf6c16620ab263cc23b5c9f7f) that if a JSF `Flash` is operated in a distributed environment, the `Flash` state needs to be stored in the session (if present) so that it can be replicated across the cluster.

While I don't necessarily take issue with this, I have the following questions:

1. What is the reasoning behind synchronizing on the global `ServletContext`? This seems overly broad and can potentially block a large number of requests.
2. Is there any way of changing this behavior, specifically for the `Flash`? I've pored over the source code, but cannot seem to find a way other than removing `<distributable/>` from the `web.xml`, or potentially unsetting the `com.sun.faces.enableDistributable` context parameter. Both of these options have an impact that is too large for my use case.

---

**Update**

I've opened a GitHub issue ([#4376](https://github.com/javaee/mojarra/issues/4376)) about this behavior on the Mojarra issue tracker.

Comment: If using sticky sessions, Infinispan session cache can be configured to be async instead of sync. In fact, IIRC, async is the default out-of-the-box setting.

Comment: @GalderZamarreño Yes, async is indeed the default setting, but that doesn't negate the fact that there are valid use cases for a synchronous session cache. Also, the option of having an asynchronous session cache does not justify blocking access to the cache on anything higher than the session level.